# Parse.com and ASP.Net Cloud code

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to Parse.com and used it's iOS SDK successfully to interact with Database at Parse.com as backend.

Now I am looking at creating a simple web service using ASP.Net and C# and want to deploy it to Parse.com Cloud. I googled extensively and not able to find any pointers on this. All the Parse Cloud Code documentation refers to writing Cloud Code using JavaScript.

Do Parse.com cloud supports ASP.Net and C#?

Answer (score 2):

Parse cloud code runs on top of the Node.js Express framework with support for a limited set of npm modules.

You could deploy your ASP.NET web site to a service like Azure websites or another webhost and look at Parse's new webhook tool that lets Parse communicate with your web application.